# substitute widetilde in one font for another in plain tex

Tags: fonts, accents, tilde, substitution

I am using newtx fonts in plain TeX. However, I prefer most of cmex to ntxexx. There is one exception (so far that I have found), the \widetilde, which is beautiful in ntxexx. I do not have any remaining families that would allow me to define both font families; I can define only cmex. How can I substitute just that one character for \widetilde in cmex or define a macro that uses it?

Here's how to see what ntxexx provides:

```
\font\tenrm=txr
\font\tenex=ntxexx
\textfont3=\tenex

\tenrm I see $\widetilde {f(x)}$.

\bye
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you really used up all 16 math families? Maybe some of them can be dealt with in a different way.

Comment: Yes, I used them all. I defined only a few myself; I have not counted where they all get used. However, I have an idea for doing this. So far, I got it to work if I use ntxexx as the default and put in cmex10; I may be able to get it to work the other way too.

Comment: If you're using math families only for alphabets such as `\it` or `\bf`, there are workarounds.

Comment: I have a few math families, such as blackboard bold and math bold italic. What are the workarounds?

Comment: `\def\mathit#1{{\mathchoice{\hbox{\tenit #1}}{\hbox{\tenit #1}}{\hbox{\sevenit #1}}{\hbox{\fiveit #1}}}}` Slower, but spares a math family; you need to call it like `\mathit{R}` instead of `{\it R}`. Of course you have to remove the math text italic family from the plain format, which shouldn't be difficult (just reassign its number).

Comment: If you don't need `\itfam`, `\slfam` or `\ttfam` (the last two are obvious candidates), just reassign their numbers (4, 5 and 7 respectively). If you decide to reassign `\ttfam=7`, just add `\def\tt{\tentt}`, although the standard definition will do no harm, if you don't use `\tt` in math mode.

Comment: I think I don't use slant, so I could replace that; thanks. Although I think I do not use \tt in math mode, I do use it in different sizes, so I don't think I can get rid of \ttfam.

Comment: Your solution using mathchoice is good, but I think it needs more like in my answer. What it does is adapt my answer to various possible math sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon the idea of switching the math extension font back and forth:

```
\font\tenrm=txr

% don't perpetuate the error
\font\tenntex=ntxexx \font\sevenntex=ntxexx at 7pt \font\fiventex=ntxexx at 5pt
\font\tencmex=cmex10 \font\sevencmex=cmex7 \font\fivecmex=cmex5

\def\cmex{\textfont3=\tencmex \scriptfont3=\sevencmex \scriptscriptfont3=\fivecmex}
\def\ntex{\textfont3=\tenntex \scriptfont3=\sevenntex \scriptscriptfont3=\fiventex}

\cmex

\catcode`@=11
\def\wtld#1{\mathpalette\@wtld{#1}}
\def\@wtld#1#2{%
  \hbox{%
    $\m@th\ntex#1\widetilde{\hbox{$\m@th\cmex#1#2$}}$%
  }%
}

\tenrm I see $\widetilde {f(x)}$.

And this: $\wtld {f(x)} \wtld {\sum a_i}$

And this: $\wtld {f(x)} \sum \wtld {a_n}$

And in subscripts: $X_{\wtld{f+g}}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. There is a caution: if one has the line \input amssym.def, then it will not work when the thing under the tilde is too long. I tried to save the old \widetilde, but could not get that to work. amssym.def redefines \widetilde (lines 85-87). I resorted to inputting my own amssym.def, with those lines commented out. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @RussLyons Redefine `\widetilde` to be the same as in Plain after loading `amssym.def`: `\def\widetilde{\mathaccent"0365 }`

Comment: Yes, that works. I must have tried a variant that did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it (though possibly complications will arise in some situations):

```
\font\tenrm=txr
\font\tenex=ntxexx
\font\tencmex=cmex10
\textfont3=\tencmex

\def\wtld#1{\hbox{$\textfont3=\tenex \widetilde {#1}$}}

\tenrm I see $\widetilde {f(x)}$.

And this: $\wtld {f(x)} \wtld {\sum a}$

And this: $\wtld {f(x)} \sum \wtld {a_n}$

\bye
```

[image]